# How to handle file paths with whitespace during drag and drop import in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which allows me to import multiple PDF file paths by using drag and drop action. However, there is an issue when importing file paths that contain whitespace, as it causes the path to split into two separate data.

For example, instead of having the correct file path `['C:/Users/user123/Desktop/hash/pdf/02. pdf_file.pdf']`, it gets split into `['C:/Users/user123/Desktop/hash/pdf/02.', 'pdf_file.pdf']`.

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinterdnd2 as tkdnd
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import sys

root = tkdnd.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")
root.title("PDF Merger")
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.drop_target_register(tkdnd.DND_FILES)
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

def on_drop(event):
    try:
        file_paths = event.data.strip("{}").split()
        print(file_paths)
        file_paths.sort()
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(file_paths[0])
        pdf_count = len(file_paths)

        pdf_writer = PdfFileMerger()
        pdf_merger = PdfFileWriter()

        for i in range(len(file_paths)):
            # Eğer sayfa sayısı tek ise, son sayfaya boş bir sayfa ekleyin
            if PdfFileReader(open(file_paths[i], "rb")).getNumPages() % 2 != 0:
                blank_page = PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'blank.pdf'), 'rb'))
                input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_paths[i], "rb"))

                for page_num in range(input_pdf.numPages):
                    pdf_merger.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page_num))
                for page_num in range(blank_page.numPages):
                    pdf_merger.addPage(blank_page.getPage(page_num))

            else:
                input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_paths[i], "rb"))

                for page_num in range(input_pdf.numPages):
                    pdf_merger.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page_num))

        # Yeni PDF dosyasını oluşturun ve içeriğini kaydedin
        output_pdf = open(os.path.join(folder_path, "MERGED-PDF.pdf"), 'wb')
        pdf_merger.write(output_pdf)

    except Exception as e:
        input_box.delete(0, tk.END)
        input_box.insert(tk.END, "Error: " + str(e))

root.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", on_drop)

label = tk.Label(root, text="Drag and drop PDF files to merge:")
label.pack()

input_box = tk.Entry(root, width=50, justify="center")
input_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: r'C:/Users/user123/Desktop/hash/pdf/02/ pdf_file.pdf'

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using `pypdf` instead of `PyPDF4`. Look at the latest release / the stars on Github / answers to issues / open bug tickets / new features / ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you cannot just split the string by space.  You need to find a way to split the string by going through the string character by character:

- initialize the default separator of filepath to *space*
- when next *space* is found, store the filepath between the two spaces
- when the character "{" is found, then it is the start of a filepath with spaces and you need to set the ending separator to "}" and store the filepath between "{" and "}"

Below is the function to split the string based on the above logic:

```py
def split(text):
    SPACE = " "
    sep = SPACE     # default separator
    filepaths = []  # list to store the filepaths
    s = ""          # filepath string
    for c in text:
        if c == sep:  # at the end of a token
            filepaths.append(s)  # save the filepath
            if sep == "}":
                sep = None
            s = ""       # reset filepath
        elif c == "{":   # start of a filepath with space
            sep = "}"    # set ending separator
        elif c == SPACE and sep is None:
            sep = SPACE  # set ending separator
        else:
            s += c       # append character to filepath
    if s:
        filepaths.append(s) # add the last filepath
    return filepaths
```

Then you can use the above function to split the filepaths dropped:

```py
def on_drop(event):
    try:
        file_paths = split(event.data)
        print(file_paths)
        ...
    ...
```